# Time Series Forecasting: ARIMA/VARIMA vs Machine Learning/Deep Learning

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, forecasting, arima, lstm

I am working on the development of a time series forecasting, and I have some doubts on which model I should use to achieve better results.

**PREMISE:**

- **Multivariate Time Series:** my time series is a multivariate one, with different series (features) and a target series.
- **Seasonality:** I am pretty sure that there are seasonal patterns and periods that affect the time series behaviour.

Some of my collegue have suggested the use of statistical models like *ARIMA/VARIMA* (the which I am not familiar with). I know that the basic concept behind this model is to "filter out" the meaningful pattern from the series (trend, seasonality, etc), in order to obtain a *stationary time series* (e.g. a series with constant mean/variance, which represent basically noise). Basically capturing the time series behaviour and patterns useful for the predictions.

I, in contrast, am more familiar with Deep Learning models (e.g. *LSTM, RNN*) and traditional machine learning models (*Random Forest*). Some of these models have a sort of memory, others not.

**QUESTIONS:**

**Is there some thumb rule to choose between these models? For example, knowing that my time series has some well known pattern like seasonality, trend, etc., why should I use ARIMA instead of Random Forest model or an LSTM? How can I make sure that I am using ARIMA correctly (underlying assumptions)**?

**WHAT I KNOW:**

- Usually, time series datasets are smaller in size than other big datasets, and deep learning models are not so powerful on this kind of data. Some of these models (RNN/LSTM) take into consideration the sequentiality of the data.
- Classical machine learning models don't take into consideration the sequentiality of the data, but work better an smaller dataset (Random Forest).
- Classical statistical models are statistically robust, but they work with some kind of assumptions on the time series.
- With a smaller dataset, usually traditional machine learning models perform better working on the features engineering and model tuning.

Comment: This article compares classic statistical time series models with ML models. Makridakis, Spilotis and Assimakopoulos, Statistical and Machine Learning forecasting methods: Concerns and ways forward, 2018, https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0194889

Comment: I believe that in the above reference the authors consider only univariate time series

Answer (score 2):

As a personal rule of thumb I begin by applying simple statistical models (ARIMA, exponential smoothing) because they require less computations and are generally more interpretable. Moreover, there exist automated packages (such as the [forecast](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/forecast/versions/8.12#:%7E:text=The%20R%20package%20forecast%20provides,models%20and%20automatic%20ARIMA%20modelling.) package) that take care the task of model selection.

Generally, I would expect better predictive performance by applying advanced machine learning algorithms, especially when there are a lot of external predictors. However, there is no guarantee about that. In any case, you have to consider how much time you want to devote in constructing a model, hyperparameter tuning, etc.